# Why do you need lots of randomness for effective encryption?

Tags: algorithm, encryption

I've seen it mentioned in many places that randomness is important for generating keys for symmetric and asymmetric cryptography and when using the keys to encrypt messages.

Can someone provide an explanation of how security could be compromised if there isn't enough randomness?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Randomness means unguessable input. If the input is guessable, then the output can be easily calculated. That is bad.

For example, Debian had a long standing bug in its SSL implementation that failed to gather enough randomness when creating a key. This resulted in the software generating one of only 32k possible keys. It is thus easily possible to decrypt anything encrypted with such a key by trying all 32k possibilities by trying them out, which is very fast given today's processor speeds.

Answer (score 4):

The important feature of most cryptographic operations is that they are easy to perform if you have the right information (e.g. a key) and infeasible to perform if you don't have that information.

For example, symmetric cryptography: if you have the key, encrypting and decrypting is easy.  If you don't have the key (and don't know anything about its construction) then you must embark on something expensive like an exhaustive search of the key space, or a more-efficient cryptanalysis of the cipher which will nonetheless require some extremely large number of samples.

On the other hand, if you have any information on likely values of the key, your exhaustive search of the keyspace is much easier (or the number of samples you need for your cryptanalysis is much lower).  For example, it is (currently) infeasible to perform 2^128 trial decryptions to discover what a 128-bit key actually is.  If you know the key material came out of a time value that you know within a billion ticks, then your search just became 340282366920938463463374607431 times easier.

Answer (score 2):

To decrypt a message, you need to know the right key.

The more possibly keys you have to try, the harder it is to decrypt the message.

Taking an extreme example, let's say there's no randomness at all. When I generate a key to use in encrypting my messages, I'll *always* end up with the exact same key. No matter where or when I run the keygen program, it'll always give me the same key.

That means anyone who have access to the program I used to generate the key, can trivially decrypt my messages. After all, they just have to ask it to generate a key too, and they get one identical to the one I used.

So we need some randomness to make it unpredictable which key you end up using. As David Schmitt mentions, Debian had a bug which made it generate only a small number of unique keys, which means that to decrypt a message encrypted by the default OpenSSL implementation on Debian, I just have to try this smaller number of possible keys. I can ignore the vast number of other valid keys, because Debian's SSL implementation will never generate those.

On the other hand, if there was enough randomness in the key generation, it's impossible to guess *anything* about the key. You have to try every possible bit pattern. (and for a 128-bit key, that's a lot of combinations.)

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with some of the basic reasons for cryptography:

- Make sure a message isn't altered in transit (Immutable)
- Make sure a message isn't read in transit (Secure)
- Make sure the message is from who it says it's from (Authentic)
- Make sure the message isn't the same as one previously sent (No Replay)
- etc

There's a few things you need to include, then, to make sure that the above is true.  One of the important things is a random value.

For instance, if I encrypt "Too many secrets" with a key, it might come out with "dWua3hTOeVzO2d9w"

There are two problems with this - an attacker might be able to break the encryption more easily since I'm using a very limited set of characters.  Further, if I send the same message again, it's going to come out exactly the same.  Lastly, and attacker could record it, and send the message again and the recipient wouldn't know that I didn't send it, even if the attacker didn't break it.

If I add some random garbage to the string each time I encrypt it, then not only does it make it harder to crack, but the encrypted message is different each time.

The other features of cryptography in the bullets above are fixed using means other than randomness (seed values, two way authentication, etc) but the randomness takes care of a few problems, and helps out on other problems.

A bad source of randomness limits the character set again, so it's easier to break, and if it's easy to guess, or otherwise limited, then the attacker has fewer paths to try when doing a brute force attack.

-Adam

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern in cryptography is the following (sending text from alice to bob):

```
Take plaintext p
Generate random k
Encrypt p with k using symmetric encryption, producing crypttext c
Encrypt k with bob's private key, using asymmetric encryption, producing x
Send c+x to bob
Bob reverses the processes, decrypting x using his private key to obtain k
```

The reason for this pattern is that symmetric encryption is much faster than asymmetric encryption. Of course, it depends on a good random number generator to produce k, otherwise the bad guys can just guess it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a "card game" analogy: Suppose we play several rounds of a game with the same deck of cards. The shuffling of the deck between rounds is the primary source of randomness. If we didn't shuffle properly, you could beat the game by predicting cards.

When you use a poor source of randomness to generate an encryption key, you significantly reduce the entropy (or uncertainty) of the key value. This could compromise the encryption because it makes a brute-force search over the key space much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Work out [this](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=59) problem from Project Euler, and it will really drive home what "lots of randomness" will do for you. When I saw this question, that was the first thing that popped into my mind.

Using the method he talks about there, you can easily see what "more randomness" would gain you.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty good paper that outlines why not being careful with randomness can lead to insecurity:

- http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~daw/papers/ddj-netscape.html

This describes how back in 1995 the Netscape browser's key SSL implementation was vulnerable to guessing the SSL keys because of a problem seeding the PRNG.